# Just what exactly is the performance loss in adding a table that gets joined on every request?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join, database-design

I'm working on an application that previously had unique handles for users only--but now we want to have handles for events, groups, places... etc. Unique string identifiers for many different first class objects. I understand the thing to do is adopt something like the Party Model, where every entity has its own unique partyId and handle. That said, that means on pretty much every data-fetching query, we're adding a join to get that handle! Certainly for every user.

So just what is the performance loss here? For a table with just three or four columns, is a join like this negligible? Or is there a better way of going about this?

Example Table Structure:

```
Party
   int id
   int party_type_id
   varchar(256) handle

Events
   int id
   int party_id
   varchar(256) name
   varchar(256) time
   int place_id

Users
   int id
   int party_id
   varchar(256) first_name
   varchar(256) last_name

Places
   int id
   int party_id
   varchar(256) name
```

-- EDIT --

I'm getting a bad rating on this question, and I'm not sure I understand why. In PLAIN TERMS, I'm asking,

If I have three first class objects that must all share a UNIQUE HANDLE property, unique across all three objects, does adding an additional table that must be joined with on almost any request incur a significant performance hit? Is there a better way of accomplishing this in a relational database like MySQL?

**-- EDIT: Proposed Queries --**

Getting one user

```
SELECT * FROM Users u LEFT JOIN Party p ON u.party_id = p.id WHERE p.handle='foo'
```

Searching users

```
SELECT * FROM Users u LEFT JOIN Party p ON u.party_id = p.id WHERE p.handle LIKE '%foo%'
```

Searching all parties... I guess I'm not sure how to do this in one query. Would you have to select all Parties matching the handle and then get the individual objects in separate queries? E.g.

```
db.makeQuery(SELECT * FROM Party p WHERE p.handle LIKE '%foo%')
.then(function (results) {
     // iterate through results and assemble lists of matching parties by type, then get those objects in separate queries
})
```

This last example is what I'm most concerned about I think. Is this a reasonable design?

Comment: The join should be performant if the all join fields are indexed. You should use `EXPLAIN` to discover optimizations for complex join queries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: It's not obvious from your question what you try to achieve and what variants you came up, but. If the question about DB structure and use 2nd or third form of normalization, better use 3rd. join on primary key will not affect your performance much, but adding columns like option_title, option_title2  will complicate your logic.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by '2nd or third form of normalization'?

Comment: @leepowers Thank you! I didn't even know about EXPLAIN

Comment: I mean either extend one table with columns, or have related tables, ex.:(user(id,name, place_1,place_2)  or user(id,name) + place(id,name,location) + user_places(user_id,place_id))

Comment: @2oppin I don't think you're answering my question. I need to provide a unique handle for every object, whether it be an event, a place, or a userr

Comment: Show us proposed queries.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Thanks @RickJames

Comment: With an index starting with `party_id`, the `JOIN` does not cost much.  Without it, it costs a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries you show should be blazingly fast on any modern implementation, and should scale to tens or hundreds of thousands of millions of records without too much trouble.

Relational Database Management Systems (of which MySQL is one) are designed explicitly for this scenario.

In fact, the slow part of your second query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u LEFT JOIN Party p ON u.party_id = p.id WHERE p.handle LIKE '%foo%'
```

is going to be `WHERE p.handle LIKE '%foo%'` as this will not be able to use an index. Once you have a large table, this part of the query will be many times slower than the join.

Comment: What about returning search results across the other tables? Can it be done in a single query or am I right in thinking they'll need to be separated out after the initial search on the Party?